# Как удалить минимальный элемент в массиве. Как исправить ошибку в функции coppi?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Заполнить элементы двумерного массива натуральными числами. Из каждой нечётной (нумерация начинается с 0) строки удалить минимальный элемент. Количество чисел в строке может быть различным, последнее число - 0
[image: Как решить эту оишбку]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void inputRowsCols(int* rows) {
    printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' ");
    while (scanf_s("%d", rows) != 1 || *rows <= 0 || getchar() != ('\n')) {
        printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' \a");
        rewind(stdin);
    }
}

int** Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int** arr;
    arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));//+
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
    }
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти");//ошибка выделения памяти
        return 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int cols(int** arr, int row) {
    int cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        if (arr[row][i] != 0) {
            cols++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return cols;
}

void printMatrix(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols(arr, i); j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != 0)
                printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void input_Matrix(int** arr, int rows, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int breakk = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < *cols && breakk == 0; j++) {
            printf("Input arr[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            while (scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("Enter element, row: %d, cols: %d ->", i + 1, j + 1);
                rewind(stdin);
            }
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                breakk = 1;
                if (i != rows - 1) {
                    printf("Next row->\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                (*cols)++;
                arr[i] = (int*)realloc(arr[i], (*cols) * sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}

void coppi(int*** arr, int rows,int* cols) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i < cols; i + 2) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (arr[i][temp] > arr[i][j]) {
                temp = j;
            }

        }
        cols--;
        for (int j = temp; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][temp] = arr[i][j + 1];

        }
        ***arr = realloc(***arr, (*cols) * sizeof(int));
        i--;
    }
    
}
int main() {


    int rows = 1, cols = 1;
    inputRowsCols(&rows);

    int** arr = Matrix(rows, &cols);
    input_Matrix(arr, rows, &cols);

    printf("\n\nYour matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

    coppi(&arr, rows,&cols);

    printf("\n\nNew matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

    free(*arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [3-х звезднычный программист](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: `int*** arr` - это указатель на массив `int**`. Использовать так : `( * arr ) [ i ] [ j ]` ;;; непонятно что вы хотите увеличить здесь : `***arr = realloc(***arr, (*cols) * sizeof(int));` ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Тип `int * *` представляет собой массив строк матрицы. И типы такие :

```
arr        == int * *
arr[i]     == int *
arr[i][j]  == int
```

Тип `int * * *` - это указатель на этот массив. А чтобы его использовать надо массив получить по указателю и у него типы :

```
arr            == int * * *
* arr          == int * *
(* arr)[i]     == int *
(* arr)[i][j]  == int
```

Так как вы в матрице изменять количество строк не будете, то передавать аргументом адрес матрицы с тремя звёздочками не стоит - вы запутаетесь.

Изменение размера строки вы сделали бестолковое.

```
***arr = realloc(***arr, (*cols) * sizeof(int));

arr       == int * * *
* arr     == int * *
* * arr   == int *
* * * arr == int
```

так как запись `***arr` имеет тип `int`, а нужно было указатель на `i`-ую строку.

Запись цикла ужасная

```
for (int i = 1; i < cols; i + 2) {
```

первый индекс должен быть равен нулю, цикл идёт по строкам, а вы идёте до **указателя** на количество столбцов, индекс `i` вообще не меняете так как сложение без сохранения результата - это бессмысленная операция.

Везде надо было использовать значение `* cols` , а не указатель.

Удаление элемента не делающее смещение

```
arr[i][temp] = arr[i][j + 1];
```

нужно заменить на

```
arr[i][j] = arr[i][j + 1];
```

Вот из за этих замечаний получается такая функция :

```
void coppi(int * * arr, int rows,int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
        int temp = 0 ;
        for (int j = 1; j < (*cols); j++) {
            if (arr[i][temp] > arr[i][j]) {
                temp = j;
            }
        }
        (*cols)--;
        for (int j = temp; j < (*cols); j++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j + 1];
        }
        arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], (*cols) * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

main :

```
coppi ( arr , rows , & cols ) ;
```

Comment: Функция ничего не удаляет. Все осттается так,как и было

Comment: тогда ещё такое : `arr[i][j] = arr[i][j + 1];`

Comment: но функция печати у вас написана до нулевого значения, как вы определите если память укоротили `realloc`? может просто ставить в конце число ноль без `realloc`?